# Find the exact values without using a calculator of cos^-1(-1/2), tan^-1(-√3/3) and sec^-1 (2)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How do I solve this problems?  The inverse of cosine is secant and the the inverse of tan is cotangent and the inverse of secant is cosine. Is that how I should think of it?

Comment: The inverse of `cos` is `arccos` and...

Comment: You really should not use the (calculus) tag for these trigonometric problems: use the (algebra-Precalculus) and (trigonometry) tags instead.

Comment: when we say "inverse" we usually mean "functional inverse" (e.g. $f(g(x))=x$ implies that $f$ and $g$ are inverses). When we say "multiplicative inverse" we mean that the 2 quantities are "reciprocals" (e.g. $f(x)g(x)=1$). Note that $\cos(x)\sec(x)=1$, but $\cos(\sec(x))\ne x$

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of $\cos$ is not $\sec$. You are mixing up "inverse" with "reciprocal". For every $x$ we have 
$$ \cos x = \frac{1}{\sec x}. $$
But you are not asked to look at the reciprocal functions, but the inverse ones, where the inverse of - say - $\cos$ is given by the property 
$$ \cos^{-1}(\cos x) = x $$
So you have to solve the equations 
$$ \cos x_1 = -\frac 12, \quad \tan x_2 = -\frac{\sqrt 3}3, \quad \sec x_3 = 2. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you're not already familiar with the unit circle, you should be! It renders all three of your questions practically trivial.

[image]
(image courtesy of [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle))

Comment: It is far more than just a *hint*.